# QGIS Legend for multi-band Raster

Tags: qgis-3, visualisation

Is there a simple way to generate labels for a multiband Raster in QGIS like it is implemented as Default in ArcGIS?
I want to write a Variable Name of each Band in the legend

ArcGIS example:
[image]